# Minikube on Windows with VirtualBox: Connection attempt fail

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I got Kubernetes Minikube on my laptop (4cores, 8 GB RAM). I just performed the basic installation steps (got *miniKube* and *kubectl*, enabled the BIOS virtualization) and I am able to start the cluster:

```
C:\Users\me>minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes cluster...
Starting VM...
SSH-ing files into VM...
Setting up certs...
Starting cluster components...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.
```

However, when I try to interact with the cluster, I allways get the same error, sample:

```
C:\Users\me>kubectl get pods --context=minikube
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party
did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I execute `minikube ip` and I ping the result IP and I get a response. Also I tried to give more memory (3Gb vs the standard 2Gb) and nothing changed.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. As I'm on Windows 10, I tried with Hyper-V too, but the problem is still there.

Comment: I did not understand the problem, but it does work now. In a nutshell, I simply restarted the minikube vm (```minikube stop``` then ```minikube start```).
No idea of what happened...

Comment: The server is not being reached and the connection failed. Verify that your firewall rules are not blocking the server.

Comment: If you were able to solve this issue, please consider posting a reply, so the community can benefit from your experience.

Comment: I couldn´t make it work (after checking the firewall, even disabling it)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue as above. I found out that `kubectl` couldn't connect to the cluster and would throw up the error when i'm on a VPN connection. When I turned off my VPN client, it started working as fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be some problem with the cluster, when I run minikube status I've got the mixed results of cluster running and cluster stopped:

First run:

```
c:\> minikube status
```

> minikube: Running
>
> cluster: Stopped
>
> kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.100

Second run:

> minikube: Running
>   cluster: Running
>   kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.100

Third run:

> minikube: Running
>
> cluster: Stopped
>
> kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.100

The service is flapping.

UPDATED:
Connecting to the minikube vm using minikube ssh I realized the kubeconfig file have wrong path separator for certificates generated by minikube automatic configuration. The path on kubeconfig file stands for `\var\lib\localkube\certs\ca.cert` and it have to be `/var/lib/localkube/certs/ca.cert` and so on...

To update the file I have to copy the content of the orignal file to my desktop, fix the directory separators and save the correct file to `/var/lib/localkube/kubeconfig` and restart the service using:

```
sudo systemclt restart localkube.
```

I hope everyone can use minikube with this tip.

Answer (score 0):

If it keep to hit 8443 connection issue when changed work environment, would simplify turn off TLS verification for minikube local cluster if there is not clue.

https://github.com/robertluwang/docker-hands-on-guide/blob/master/minikube-no-tls-verify.md

Hope it is helpful for you.

BR/
Robert

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation:

for Troubleshooting
Run `minikube start --alsologtostderr -v=7` to debug crashes

I had the same problem:

check if a some service of a VPN is running by checking the task management, for me, I had a running service of my VPN, so kill the task and try to run the command showed above